# Apple logos within iOS app got rejected

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

My app got rejected by the Apple because I used Apple logos:

> Your app does not comply with the Guidelines for Using Apple's Trademarks and Copyrights. Specifically, your app includes:
>
> - Apple trademark, Apple logo, imagery - or likeness - in the binary and metadata.

Which is true I did use it. Although I've found an app that has those too (HUAWEI HiLink (Mobile WiFi))

Attaching the image of the app below

[image]

My question is can I somehow get passed without removing those logos or Apple's guidelines aren't exactly equal for everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to direct your question at Apple.

It is naturally Apple's own choice to whom they license their intellectual property such as trademarks and logos - and under which conditions.

You haven't described how you used the logos in your apps. Perhaps you did so in a manner that violates Apple's "[Guidelines for Using Apple Trademarks and Coprights](https://www.apple.com/uk/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html)".

Or perhaps Huawei simply has an agreement with Apple or is a larger customer with Apple.

Comment: Fair enough I guess..